# Find <li> tag by its child tag <a> href value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to find Li tag which has a child tag  by its Href value. By this I need to set class for that li tag.

**My HTML**

```
<div id="tabs" class="tab_wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabSubject" data-toggle="tab">Subject</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabContract" data-toggle="tab">Contract</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabNeighbourhood" data-toggle="tab">Neighborhood</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabSite" data-toggle="tab">Site</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabImprovements" data-toggle="tab">Improvements</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabSupplemental" data-toggle="tab">Supplemental Data</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.Active
{
    color:red;
}
```

For example I have to set class "Active" for li tag which has href value "#tabNeighbourhood", so that li tag will be like

```
<li class="active"><a href="#tabNeighbourhood" data-toggle="tab">Neighborhood</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: But to addtheclass on wich event? on click that `a` find the parent `li`?  If it is that way just bind the click on the `li`

Comment: Sorry. It too nesting, so i dont know how to start. @A.Wolff

Comment: @Danko I have to write this in Initial loading event

Comment: @MohitArora Thanks but i dont want this using click event or this keyword

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/ppw7pq22/2/

Comment: So many answers and no upvotes ....

Comment: Thanks for all..I not able to upvote coz of my reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li', '#tabs')
  .filter(function() {
    return !! $(this).find('a[href="#tabNeighbourhood"]').length;
  })
  .addClass('active');
```

I refer you to [the official docs](http://api.jquery.com/) for explanation of the single parts.

Comment: Thanks its working as expected but i want to remove class if any other li tag which has `class="active"`

Answer (score 2):

Using `:has()` selector:

```
$('li:has(a[href="#tabNeighbourhood"])').addClass('active');
```

This will add class `active` to any LI containing anchor with specific href attribute.

Comment: Thanks its working as expected but i want to remove class if any other li tag which has `class="active"`

Comment: @Vignesh `$('li.active').removeClass('active');` ??? What is your question? And please, don't add new question in comment, ask a new one

Comment: +1. More concise solution than my `.filter()` approach.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) :

```
$("ul.nav > li").removeClass("active");             // Clear all li's class attributes.
$("a[href='#tabNeighborhood']").parent().addClass("active");  // Add active to neighborhood.
```

Comment: That's not the ID, that's the href attribute

Answer (score 1):

**Try Below Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').find('a').each(function(){
     if($(this).attr('href')=="#tabNeighbourhood"){
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("Active");
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, You can achieve by CSS alone:

```
a[href$='#tabNeighbourhood']
{
 color:red;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je8nmc22/)**

JQuery method (using `:has()` selector):

```
$('ul li:has(a[href="#tabNeighbourhood"])').addClass('Active');
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je8nmc22/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using your HTML structure you can use an immediate children selector `>`, `has` selector and a selector on `href` attribute.

Code:

```
$('#tabs>ul>li:has(a[href="#tabNeighbourhood"])').addClass('active');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swvzot7f/

Answer (score 0):

Try it by yourself. Here is an algorithm if you consider it too complex:

1. Search for needed `<a>` [by attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
2. Select the [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) of `<a>` that was found.
3. [Add class](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to that parent.

Answer is pretty simple, so I do think it is much more important to show you the way of thinking instead of feeding with ready made-up solution.

**EDIT**

Just in case you fail I decided to add a solution too:

```js
$( "a[href='NEEDED HREF TO SEARCH']" ).parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code (vanilla js :-) shows you how to add a class to an HTML element which ha specific `href` value. Just enter in the field the href value you want to search, it will add a class active, example try: `#tabSubject` or `#tabImprovements`. I hope it is what you need.

```js
function setActive(){
 var elm = document.getElementsByName('findElm')[0],
  searchElm = elm.value,
  targetStr = 'a[href*="' + searchElm + '"]',
  target = document.querySelector(targetStr);
  target.classList.add('Active');
  
}
```

```css
.Active
{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs" class="tab_wrapper">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabSubject" data-toggle="tab">Subject</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabContract" data-toggle="tab">Contract</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabNeighbourhood" data-toggle="tab">Neighborhood</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabSite" data-toggle="tab">Site</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabImprovements" data-toggle="tab">Improvements</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabSupplemental" data-toggle="tab">Supplemental Data</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<input type="text" name="findElm" value="#tabImprovements"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" onclick="setActive();">
```

Answer (score -1):

css: Use the nth-child concept(Best Practice)

```
.tab_wrapper ul :nth-child(3) a {
    color:red;
}
```